# How can I print all notifications from NotificationCenter in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, printing, notifications, notificationcenter

For general debugging I thought it would be really useful to find out all notifications being published by NotificationCenter and print them to the console. I couldn't find a post on this so I thought I would share how I achieved this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    let notes = NotificationObserver()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
    }
}


class NotificationObserver {
    init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(printAllNotifications),
            name: nil,
            object: nil)
    }

    @objc func printAllNotifications(_ note: Notification) {
        guard note.name != UIScreen.brightnessDidChangeNotification else { return }

        print(note.name)
    }
}
```

Essentially the name parameter of `addObserver(_:selector:name:object:)` is `optional`, and passing nil as an argument means all notifications are observed.

The function we provide to the selector parameter needs access to `Objective-C` at runtime so we mark it with `@objc`. Since `@objc` can only be used with members of classes we wrap this code in our NotificationObserver class.

Now all we need to do is create an instance of `NotificationObserver` at the entry point of our app and all notifications are printed to the console (here we exclude the `brightnessDidChangeNotification` as this seems to pollute the console and is probably not what you're looking for when using this).